# Middle click paste in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, copy-paste, codemirror

When I select text with my mouse, I can paste it using the middle click. Except in a Jupyter notebook. 
This apparently was [due to codemirror](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/HylqeCVrxbU), but the issue has since been [solved by codemirror](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/931). Does this mean there is a way to get middle click paste to work in Jupyter now?

Answer (score 0):

By accident, I found that text selected with the mouse can be pasted into a Jupyter notebook by clicking with both left and middle buttons at the same time.

However, text selected with the mouse still doesn't seem to be copied anywhere.

Comment: left+middle-button combo is not working for me on Firefox on Linux